# How to handle exceptions using EntityManager in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, exception

I have dao layer:

```
@Transactional
public class DatabaseCollectionDao implements IDatabaseCollectionDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void create(Collection collection) {
           entityManager.persist(collection);
    }
}
```

It **works correctly** but:

1. When database isn't available I have **SocketException**.
2. When database contains a duplicate key I have **SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**

I am trying to **try/catch** it inside create method:

```
@Override
    public void create(Collection collection) {
           try{
               entityManager.persist(collection);
           } catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e){
               //do smth
           }
    }
```

But Intellij says that It is **never thrown**.
When I try to try/catch **Exception** i have **UnexpectedRollbackException**.

**How to handle exceptions using JPA entityManager?**

**update**: An attempt to remove @Transactional gave nothing

P.S. To be sure i tried to try/catch it in higher layers. I don't know what i can try more to solve it.

Comment: `entity.persist(entity);` - is this code correct?

Comment: Yes, It works correctly. But when I stop db and try to send request or persist one more time this entity(with the same id) I have a such problem

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of `Entitymanager::persist` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-

Comment: oh, sorry, of course. entityManager.persist(entity);

Comment: Please show the relevant portion of your statcktrace

Comment: Stacktrace is added in the question. Maybe it's important, i configure DataSource using @Bean and commons-dbcp dependency

Comment: Your exception is being thrown by `by.training.dao.implementations.DatabaseCollectionDao.create`

Comment: Yes, i just rename it for an example. In the question DbDao equals DatabaseCollectionDao. Entity is renamed too to make this question abstract.

Comment: The problem is here, stackTrace accepted it.

Comment: Have a look at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: javadocs says about EntityExistsException when entity is exist and about PersistenceException, IllegalArgumentException, TransactionRequiredException in some other situations. I tried to try/catch them all. The result is the same, catch blocks were even not invoked

Comment: As per the javadocs *EntityExistsException - if the entity already exists. (If the entity already exists, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time.)*

Comment: I can catch only Runtime exception(runtime catch block is the last catch block). I can do it only in the layer which invokes dao layer. I can invoke getCause() - org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement - for the case with duplicate entity. But even if try to catch org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException, it skips it and catch in the last catch block - runtimeException.

Comment: catch `EntityExistsException`

Comment: check pls update in the question. I am always in RuntimeException catch block, if i have some problems with executing

Comment: As the cause i have - org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement  - when entity is duplicate. org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:  - when db isn't available

Comment: create customException handler extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler .  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException::class)
    fun handleConstraintViolation(ex: ConstraintViolationException, request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<Any> {} this kotlin snippet u can convert to java easily

Comment: Oh god, it works. Ty!

Comment: give up vote if it works :D

Comment: stackTrace say about SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException but intellij don't permit me to catch it , javadocs say about EntityExistsException. Indeed I should  catch ContaintViolationException. And i have negative rep on the question. How can I predict it?

Comment: It happens when people couldn't understand the questions properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create customException handler extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler . @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException::class) fun handleConstraintViolation(ex: ConstraintViolationException, request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity {} this kotlin snippet u can convert to java easily –